# discrete sine transform MATRIX

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I have written a script which gives discrete sine transform (DST) matrix. However, it returns zero for the first row. Although it should not be zero for the first row.

```
function x = dstmtx(n)
[cc,rr] = meshgrid(0:n-1);
x = sqrt(2 / n) * sin(pi * (2*cc + 1) .* rr / (2 * n));
x(1,:) = c(1,:) / sqrt(2);
```

it returns this:

```
0         0         0         0
0.2706    0.6533    0.6533    0.2706
0.5000    0.5000   -0.5000   -0.5000
0.6533   -0.2706   -0.2706    0.6533
```

Comment: Where's the math you based this on?

Comment: with the first row's `rr` being 0, you get `sin(<something> * 0)` which is 0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As @Adriaan pointed out, you would need to clarify the math *before* asking the question. For debugging questions, always include the expected behaviors. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In your case, the issue seems to be a simple misunderstanding of the underlying math. And that will be clear if you go through the process of clarifying expected behavior of your code.

Comment: A simple fix would be to change to `meshgrid(0.5:n)`.

Answer (score -1):

The sine of zero is zero

```
sin(0) == 0
```

So the first row of the DST transform matrix is all zeros.